# How do I set directory permission in Proguard output?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

Proguard does something strange. As a out I have two jars, one guarded by Proguard and the second not.

I set up Proguard to do nothing, only to create "guarded" jar. (because of the issue and because of testing)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.proguard.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>obfuscation-packaging</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <proguardVersion>${tool.proguard.version}</proguardVersion>
                            <includeDependency>false</includeDependency>
                            <obfuscate>false</obfuscate>
                            <injar>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</injar>
                            <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-proguard.${project.packaging}</outjar>
                            <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>${tool.proguard.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Config file:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/jmods/java.base.jmod

-dontnote
-dontwarn
-keepparameternames
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep class org.** { *; }


-keep public class * {
  <methods>;
}
```

Not touched by proguard jar has a following list of access permissions.

[image]

As you see D drwxr-xr-x

But created jar by Proguard has almost nothing

[image]

What could be wrong? How to solve this issue?

Environment

2. Proguard version 6.1.0beta1
3. Maven plugin 2.0.14
4. Java: 10
5. OS Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
-keepdirectories
```

To avoid removing meta data.